# Address: byte to word conversion

Tags: c++, byte, cpu-word

I'm doing this training (C++) where I am modelling a memory block which is defined as following:

```
memory(const std::string& name, unsigned long long size)
```

So the size argument must be specified in words (32-bits).

In the training, the example defines:

```
enum { MEM_SIZE = 0x10000 }; //MEM_SIZE in bytes
```

And when defining the memory object:

```
mMemory("mMemory", MEM_SIZE >> 2); //shifting right twice => dividing by 4
```

My question is, how is shifting the MEM_SIZE by 2 converting it to a word address ?

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't convert to a word *address*, it converts to a word *size*.  Clue: How big is a "word" in this context?  Consider the relationship between shift and division.

Comment: Is `MEM_SIZE` in *bytes*? What is a "word" on your platform? Is is a 4-byte integer value? Then think about what right-shifting means and what it's equivalent of.

Comment: Oh, I got it I think! `MEM_SIZE` is the size in bytes of my memory unit, and dividing it by 4 (shifting right twice) gives me the actual number of 32-bit data. Thanks!